# How to remove godaddy parking message from google search results for my website?

Tags: search, dns, search-engine, google-search

I bought a domain from Godaddy. I created my web app and hosted on AWS. On opening the URL, it opens my website correctly as I have set the CNAME and other DNS parameters. However, if I do a google search for my website, in the description of the search result it shows this message:

```
This web page is parked FREE, courtesy of GoDaddy.com New .COMs ...
```

I submitted the page for indexing on [google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) . Didn't help. How do I fix it?

Comment: These things can take time to propagate, it takes Google awhile to update its results and start showing your website information.

Comment: Its been 4 days. Not sure how long to wait. I guess i will contact godaddy support for a solution.

Comment: Can you tell us what happened with this please?

Comment: Took a week to get resolved automatically. I added metatags of description to the site and submitted to google to re-index.

Answer (score -1):

login to your godaddy account-> domains->dns->domain forward-> fill out,select box (forward and mask), add description and key words, also select box at bottom and save.